# Is "resign with effect from [date]" inclusive?

Tags: meaning, dates, subcontinental-english

> I am resigning from my post with effect from 15th April.

Does this imply that April 14th will be my last working day, or will it be April 15th?

Comment: This is the famous inclusive-or-exclusive endpoint ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

**I am resigning from my post effective at close of business on 15th April** leaves me in no doubt that you will be on duty on the 15th but not on the 16th.

Answer (score 0):

Change the sentence to read:

> "I hereby resign from my post effective as of 2400 hours 14th [or *15th*, if that's your intention] April 2003."

There's no point in sending something that you already know is unclear and ambiguous, is there? You're the one who's resigning, so you should be able to decide the time and date your resignation takes effect.

Comment: It doesn't much matter if your former employers think you're weird, of course, but this wording would have that effect. Why not say "My last working day will be Apri 15th" rather than trying to use "effective" or "with effect"?

Comment: @Kate: What I suggested is international business-speak and legal-speak, as well as very precise because it includes date and **hour** (a hangover from my days in the US Navy, which demanded such chronological precision). Moreover, the OP seems to be from India, where much of the idiomatic native Indian English sounds "weird" to North American ears. When I revise, I try to imitate the writer's voice & use their style rather than my own: less egotistical & it yields a more consistent revision in longer pieces of discourse. When in Rome....