# As of + present perfect continous sentence

Tags: phrase-requests

> As of July 2019, how many Indian players have been inducted in the ICC hall of fame?

In this sentence, is the month of July included or not?

Comment: [Is 'from {date} inclusive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110382/is-resign-with-effect-from-date-inclusive) answers that this is ambiguous, and ['as of ...'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112770/understanding-as-of-as-at-and-as-from) that 'as of' can mean (among other things)  'from'.

Answer (score -1):

When you say, "as of now," you are including "now".  Likewise, when you say, "As of July 2019," you are including July.